# Problems with Null in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want the code to display the selection in `ListBox1` in a MsgBox and "Select a Capacity" if `ListBox1` is empty/not selected.
If I try to use `IsEmpty()`, then `ListBox1.Value` is `Null`.
If I use `IsNull()`, then `ListBox1.Value` is `""`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim Cap As Integer

    If IsNull(ListBox1) = True Then
        MsgBox "Select a Capacity"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Cap = Left(ListBox1.Value, 2)
    MsgBox Cap    
End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It appears to be working now, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IsEmpty function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx) is used to check is a variable of type Variant has been initialised. It cannot be used to check if a [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862699.aspx) contains any entries.

The [IsNull function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278616.aspx) checks if a variable has been set to Null. This doesn't help with checking a ListBox for entries.

Instead, use `If ListBox1.ListCount = 0 Then` to check if the ListBox is empty and use `If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then` to check if any entries have been selected.

If the ListBox allows multiple selections at once then, as mentioned by @shoegazer100, use something like:

```
Dim rowNumber As Long
For rowNumber = 0 To (ListBox1.ListCount - 1)
    If ListBox1.Selected(rowNumber) Then
        ' do something
    End If
Next rowNumber
```

to determine which rows are currently selected (if Selected returns True for a particular row then the corresponding row in the ListBox is selected)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
If ListBox1.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Select a capacity"
    Exit Sub
End If

Cap = Left(ListBox1.Value, 2)
```

Comment: That did not work for me. The "itemsSelected" wasn't working with the Listbox1. I am using this an Or statement to accept both data types (Null and "").

Comment: `ItemsSelected` may be an Access-only property. The only other alternative I can think of would be to loop through the `ListBox1` items and use the `ListBox1.Selected` property to determine if anything has been selected.